# How do data mining classifiers behave when we add training samples to previously established training models?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, algorithms, artificial-intelligence

I have yet to choose a classifier to get my model but I wanted to see which possible classifiers fit what I'm looking for.
In fact, I need an algorithm to establish offline training this way:

- The first training starts after a month of collecting data (I know it's a short time but I want to see how it performs and how it gets better with time and more data) **=> first model is made**
- After another month, I've got data collected after two months in total, so I want to establish a new model since my training data has just doubled and the model should provide better results **=> second model**
- this continues on and on for a year...

Question1: **After two months, when I want to add the new training data, would the previous model be updated to make the new model or would the training start all over as if I don't have a previous model?**

Question2: **Do all classifiers behave the same when new training samples are introduced?**

I don't know if this is relevant, but my problem is a low-dimensional one: about 5 inputs (user location, date, time...) to predict one output.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to question 1 is that it depends on the model/optimization method used. In principle, it takes a specialized approach to use new data in order to update the model without retraining (with the entire dataset). For more on this see:
[Online machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning).

The answer to question 2 is no. As a simplistic (and hand wavy) example, consider the case where you observe a sequence of observations:
$$
(y_1, X_1),...(y_n,X_n) \in \mathbb{R^p}\times\mathbb{R},
$$
and that you are interested in estimating a linear regression:
$$
y_i = X_i\beta + \varepsilon_i.
$$
One possibility is to do so via the usual least squares estimator:
$$
\hat\beta = (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}y.
$$

Another option, in case outliers are of concern, is to use a robust estimating equation:
$$
\hat\beta = \arg\max_\beta \varphi(X\beta - y),
$$
for more on robust regression see- [Robust regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_regression). Now, suppose that the $n+1$ observation is an outlier, so for example,
$$
y_{n+1} = 10^5 * \max_{i\in 1:n} |x_i|.
$$

In this case the non-robust estimate will likely change by a lot and the robust regression estimate will not be effected.